# How to add multiple changes to DataGridTextColumn with Style using XAML in WPF application?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Adding multiple changes to cell in DataGrid.

I have DataGrid and want to add style only to one column. I managed to change background colour of my cell:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="backColour" Color="#E9E9E9" />
</DataGrid.Resources>


<DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Str" Binding="{Binding Str}">                                    
                 <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource backColour}"/>
                      </Style>
                  </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

When the row is selected text gets white, but I want to add that if is selected text is getting black. How can I add this additional change? I found how to make it black ([Setting the text Colour of a WPF DataGrid Row when row is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104646/setting-the-text-colour-of-a-wpf-datagrid-row-when-row-is-selected)) but don't know how to connect it with changing the background in the same style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the trigger from the link you provided to the `Style` you defined:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource backColour}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

But given that the `Foreground` is also black when a row is not selected, you can just make the `Foreground` to always be black:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource backColour}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```